# 2 Cells in UICollectionView row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to have 2 collectionView cells per row in my CollectionView, I want them to both be half of the width of the collectionView, but when doing that it only displays 1 cell per row, this is the code I have to size it:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width / 2, height: 190)
    }
```

I'm not sure why this shouldn't work, can anyone help out?

When I subtract some width it displays 2 per row, but then the cells' width are smaller than half of the screen size

Answer (score 1):

You need to set  `minimumLineSpacing` to 0

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

Or

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to set spacing to `0` in the `UICollectionView` attribute inspector

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you must use both via `collectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and second like below:

```
func setupCollectionView() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = .zero
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0 //as per your requirement
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0 //as per your requirement
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.yourCollectionView.frame.width / 2, height: 190)
    self.yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```